# How is the list of Related Questions generated?

Tags: discussion

Was browsing this question: [Recursive conversion to multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484358/recursive-conversion-to-multidimensional-array)

and noticed the related posts list:

[image]

Out of interest, I clicked the "Check if object is an array?" question and noticed it was a JavaScript question. The question I originally viewed had these tags:

[php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays) [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm)

How does a JS question get related to a PHP question? Is it the vagueness of the other two tags? Should related questions try to prioritise relating questions with the same language tagged over relevance of title/ambiguous tags?

Comment: Meta SE Dupe: [How are "related" questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/20473/363946)

Comment: @DavyM ah that'll be why I couldn't find it - I forget there's a world outside of SO and a whole SE ... still, have there been any changes in the last 5 years since the 2013 answer?

Comment: Yes, see the second answer, [posted in April of this year.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309038/363946)

Comment: Must be something like `SELECT * FROM RAND(MAX)`

Comment: Meanwhile in the "related" section of this question: "Do we need the [sum] tag?" ... huh? I guess this post proves its own point.